# how to get column value from xml column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

```
<value1>

<name>
 <account id="4567890" firstname="abc">
</account>
</name> 

</value1>
```

i need to take out id in account tag in xml

```
SELECT 
       T.id
     , T.request_xml.value(
          '(Value1/name/account/id)[1]', 
          'varchar(50)'
       ) AS id
FROM [table] AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use @ -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = '
<value1>
<name>
 <account id="4567890" firstname="abc">
</account>
</name> 
</value1>'

SELECT id = @XML.value('(value1/name/account/@id)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
```

Your query -

```
SELECT 
       T.id
     , T.request_xml.value(
          '(Value1/name/account/@id)[1]', --<-- @
          'varchar(50)'
       ) AS id
FROM [table] AS T
```

Comment: without declaring variable i want to select from table id as column extracted from xml what to do for that..